# How to locally change encoding?

Tags: latex, tex, lyx

I'm using LyX, but I guess a solution would be some TeX code.
I'm writing a document in English and I want to insert some Hebrew text, but the document encoding doesn't let me. Using Hebrew encoding for the entire document doesn't work as it ruins the TOC, etc. Is there a way to locally change the text's encoding?

Comment: You should look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Arabic_script I've never written anything in Hebrew, so I wouldn't know how to help you with this.

Comment: If you don't need the advanced microtypography features of pdfTeX, switch to XeTeX which has native Unicode and OpenType support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amir, I would suggest to change ALL de document encoding for some Unicode one - for example, UTF-8.  Unicode encodings can support all writing systems. Is it possible? If not, why?

Comment: When I do this I get an error that the character was "not set up to use with LaTeX".

Comment: When I changed to utf8x, the TOC turns into Hebrew (??) and all the English in the TOC is reversed.

Comment: Could you share some resumed verson of the document, or some files which produce this error? I usually recommend use XeTeX/XeLaTeX when people got weird problems with UTF-8 but it is just a general recomendation. I believe we can know better with some examples of yours.

Comment: @Amir: if you want a fixed-width, ASCII-compatible charset, Latin-8 supports Hebrew letters: you can use \RequirePackage[8859-8]{inputenc}.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution from http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/ has several examples. Take a look -- one of them must have what you need.